Highlight Cells Across Multiple Columns, Relative to Data in Multiple Other Columns with One Rule
In Google Sheets, I'm trying to consolidate multiple conditional formatting rules into one rule but I'm not sure it's possible with this particular need.
Sample/Test Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJbnndG5wdQcIx1bkKkTEXmov69nVMFtuaCOPY5TPZ4/edit?usp=sharing
A range of cells in each row (C:E) should be blacked out if B meets specific criteria. But also,
A range of cells in each row (G:I) should be blacked out if F meets specific criteria. But also,
A range of cells in each row (K:M) should be blacked out if J meets specific criteria. Etc...
Right now I am using a different conditional formatting rule for each range...
Applied to range C2:E20...
=AND( $A2<>"", ( ($B2="No")+($B2="") ) )

Applied to range G2:I20...
=AND( $A2<>"", ( ($F2="No")+($F2="") ) )

Applied to range K2:M20...
=AND( $A2<>"", ( ($J2="No")+($J2="") ) )

Does anyone know of a way to combine these rules? Perhaps with an INDIRECT reference? For example, is there a way to adapt something like this...
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)

...in a way that allows EACH RANGE a rule is applied to, to reference another column relative to the RANGE? (As opposed to, relative to EACH COLUMN.)
I have a feeling this is not possible but wanted to check with the community just in case. Maybe there's a totally different way I haven't thought of. It sure would make life a lot easier since the sheet I'm working with has a massive number of ranges that need to follow these rules.
Thank you!


Here's one approach you may test out:
Apply to range: B2:M
Custom formula is:
=and($A2<>"",let(Σ,indirect(address(row(),xmatch("*Available",$A$1:B$1,2,-1))),((Σ="No")+(Σ=""))))



Wow! That was amazingly simple and I'm able to easily adapt it for variation. Thank you so much!
